# Updating a Table with Update Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, inwhich I need to update one with the information from the other.

My first table contains information regarding the pricing of parts, 133,000 parts to be exact. This table has information regarding the: Cost, Dealer Net and List Price.

My 2nd table of specific parts that need to have the Old Cost, Old Dealer Net, and Old List price pulled from Table 1.

I am wondering how I go about importing my table that needs to be updated, and running an update query to get the information from the other table?

I can provide anything you may need to assist or clarify my question

Comment: Do you need to transfer the information from table 1 to table 2?
Will an Update statement with an inner join clause not be enough?

Comment: Essentially, I need to take the Information from table 1 (The Master List of Parts) and pull information into my Table 2(Specific list of parts). Is there a way to post attachments here? Providing a screencap might be easier to explain. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I assume I am overcomplicating this process. Im just curious as to how to do it mostly.

Comment: Colin, what are you using to store your data? Excel, Access, SQL Server or something else?
Also, are you trying to combine results from both data sets?

Comment: is this a one time thing or will you regularly be doing this update?

Comment: The original table is created in Excel, both of them. I'm just importing both Tables into Access. I am just trying to take certain data from Table1 (Cost,DLR Net and List Price) and have that information show for the parts in table2. My boss has instructed me to do this via Update Query.

Comment: More than likely a one time thing.

Comment: Now that you have imported them into Access you can just go to queries and add both tables. Then you need to find a common field on both tables to join on almost like a common denominator. Then you can just click the columns you need to see then execute the query to get the results you need.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, thats what I've been trying to do. I continue to get Type Mismatch in Expression, which means the fields do not work with each other correct?

Comment: Also, what does 'Query must have at least 1 destination field' mean when I try to run an Update Query?

Comment: Exactly right it is basically saying you cannot compare a text field to an integer field. What you could do it try to modify the table to make sure the field data types match.

Comment: If I am reading your post right I don't think you need to do an UPDATE statement. I think you can either export these query results to EXCEL or just use the MAKE TABLE option and get your results that way...

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL the query would look like this:

```
update t2
set OldCost = t1.Cost, OldDealerNet = t1.DealerNet, OldListPrice = t1.ListPrice
from table2 t2 inner join table1 as t1
on t2.fkPartId = t1.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Colin, what are you using to store your data? Excel, Access, SQL Server or something else?
Also, are you trying to combine results from both data sets?

Now that you have imported both tables into Access you can just go to queries and add both tables. Then you need to find a common field on both tables to join on almost like a common denominator. Then you can just click the columns you need to see then execute the query to get the results you need.

If you get Type Mismatch in Expression, it is basically saying you cannot compare a text field to an integer field. What you could do it try to modify the table to make sure the field data types match.

If I am reading your post right I don't think you need to do an UPDATE statement. I think you can either export these query results to EXCEL or just use the MAKE TABLE option and get your results that way...

Comment: The original table is created in Excel, both of them. I'm just importing both Tables into Access. I am just trying to take certain data from Table1 (Cost,DLR Net and List Price) and have that information show for the parts in table2. My boss has instructed me to do this via Update Query.